# How to handle constructors parameter properly

Tags: java

I am doing one of the online courses in Java and I have a bit of misunderstanding regarding Constructors parameter handling in this specific situation.
The conditions are straight forward: if a value of a parameter that is passed while calling the constructor is less than 0, the field should have value 0;
So, I am calling the constructor while creating a new object

```
       Test test = new Test(1.125, -1.0);
```

The first code sample works, and it does the job (x=1.125, y=0) but is this the right way of handling the parameter? (I have heard that it is not)
It seems that I have actually changed the parameter first and not the field.

```
public class Test{
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Test(double x, double y) {
        if(x < 0){
            x = 0;
        }
        if(y < 0){
            y = 0;
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then I have actually tried to change the field properly. Passing the same parameters while calling the constructor (1.125, -1.0).

```
public class Test{
    private double x;
    private double y;
        public Test(double x, double y) {
            if(x <= 0 && y >= 0){
                this.x = 0;
                this.y = y;
            }
            if(y <= 0 && x >= 0){
                this.y = 0;
                this.x = x;
            }
            if (x <= 0 && y <= 0){
                this.x = 0;
                this.y = 0;
            }
            else{
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
    }
}
```

For some reason, constructor call set a field value for y to -1.0.

Why?

Didn't I exclude that with my expressions?

Comment: You might want to chain the `if` blocks with and `else if (...)` statement. Otherwise the last `if-else` block is separated from the first two `if` statements.

Comment: You could use the conditional operator: `this.x = x < 0 ? 0 : x`. Or use max: `this.x = Math.max(0, x);`

Comment: There is nothing wrong in modifying the double params. They are passed in as values

Comment: As @Johnny Mopp said, you could use conditional operator. This is simple and neat

Answer (score 3):

In the case you tried the code enters the else block of the following if-else:

```java
if (x <= 0 && y <= 0)
{
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}
else
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

thus overriding the value of y that was assigned by your second if statement. You should use if-else if...else across your code.